# Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function when calling call from unit test

Tags: solidity, truffle, unittesting, mocha

I have a problematic unit test in a suite. It's pretty simple:

```
it("SapienToken deployed with SPN symbol", async function() {
    let SPN = await SapienToken.new(TokenController.address, Owned.address);
    let symbol = await SPN.symbol.call();

    assert.equal(symbol, 'SPN', 'Symbol name is not SPN');
});
```

It throws invalid number of arguments when I use call to take a public variable from a contract.

Isn't this how it's supposed to be called? What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is the constructor of SapienToken expecting as parameters?  Check if some of the parameters passed are `undefined`.